# pull.sh: line 1: cd: $'D:\\New folder (8)\r': No such file or directory

Tags: windows, bash

I am using windows bash I have pull.sh

File pull .sh

```
cd D:\\New\ folder\ \(8\)
git pull
```

I am run command `PS D:\> bash pull.sh` but it give me error even directory exists it adding r in path which I have not given

> pull.sh: line 1: cd: $'D:\New folder (8)\r': No such file or directory

Comment: And if you try it with a path that does not have spaces and silly parenthesis?

Comment: convert your file from CRLF to LF

Comment: Your script has DOS/Windows line endings, which won't work with unix tools like the shell. See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) for more info and how to solve this. Also, unix paths are different from Windows paths. I think you want `cd '/mnt/d/New folder (8)'`, but I'm not sure about that. See [this HowToGeek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/261383/how-to-access-your-ubuntu-bash-files-in-windows-and-your-windows-system-drive-in-bash/).